# Ajax Response code not working - Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am using Spring 4. I am trying to make ajax call to fetch list of applications based on the id passed. I am able to print the list in the controller. But in the response body of ajax, I am not able to get the success message in alert.

I am not really sure, if the method signature in the controller has any significant error which is avoiding the response back to the calling javascript ajax function.

Can you please let me know, why the response block is not working ?

Below is the code,

**jsp:**

```
<tr>
        <td>Category <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
        <td>
            <form:select path="categoryId" onchange="javascript:crunchifyAjax(value)" > 
                <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
                    <form:option value="${category.id}" label="${category.name}" />
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**javascript:**

```
function crunchifyAjax(categoryId) {
alert(categoryId)
$.ajax({
    url : '../public/getApplicationList',
    data: {
        categoryId : categoryId
    },          
    success : function(response){
     alert("success")

    },

});
```

}

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/public/getApplicationList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
   public @ResponseBody List<String> sectionList(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "") String categoryId,@ModelAttribute("eventReleaseForm") EventReleaseForm eventReleaseForm,BindingResult result, ModelMap model) throws NumberFormatException, FwkDBException{
    System.out.println("inside sectionList");
    System.out.println(eventReleaseForm.getCategoryId());

    List<String> lst =  new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add("hello");

    return lst;    


}
```

Comment: Have you used the browser's debug console to check the server response?

Comment: yes in chrome developer tools, it is showing jquery-1.11.1.js:9631 GET http://localhost:8080/releaseCalendar/mvc/public/getApplicationList 406 (Not Acceptable)  .   If I use a method with String return type, alert in the success block of ajax is getting called. I think, the List<String> is not able to get parsed back to ajax . Can you help me in this.

Comment: why do you use this path in ajax - ../public/getApplicationList instead of /public/getApplicationList

Comment: It seems some setting in the project related to context path, with /public/getApplicationList, my controller method is not getting invoked. I have to prefix .. to the url

Comment: I am able to get the code working. I have to add @EnableWebMvc to the controller class

Comment: hmm... weird place to put @EnableWebMvc, normally that will be part of you config.